# How can I get the column in BASH?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a large .xml file like that:

```
c1="a1" c2="b1" c3="cccc1"

c1="aa2" c2="bbbb2" c3="cc2"

c1="aaaaaa3" c2="bb3" c3="cc3"

...
```

I need the result like the following:

```
a1 b1 cccc1

aa2 bbbb2 cc2

aaaaaa3 bb3 cc3

...
```

How can I get the column in BASH?

I have the following method in PL/SQL,but it's very inconvenient:

```
SELECT C1,
       TRIM(BOTH '"' FROM REGEXP_SUBSTR(C1, '"[^"]+"', 1, 1)) c1,
       TRIM(BOTH '"' FROM REGEXP_SUBSTR(C1, '"[^"]+"', 1, 2)) c2,
       TRIM(BOTH '"' FROM REGEXP_SUBSTR(C1, '"[^"]+"', 1, 3)) c3
FROM TEST;
```

Comment: That is an example  ~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [cut](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cut):

```
cut -d'"' -f2,4,6 --output-delimiter=" " test.txt
```

Or you can use sed if the number of columns is not known:

```
sed 's/[a-z][a-z0-9]\+="\([^"]\+\)"/\1/g' < test.txt
```

**Explanation:**

- `[a-z][a-z0-9]\+` - matches a string starting with a alpha char followed by any number of alphanumeric chars
- `"\([^"]\+\)"` - captures any string inside the quotes
- `\1` - represents the captured string that in this case is used to replace the entire match

A perl approach (based on the [awk answer by @A-Ray](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33276319/939457))

```
perl -F'"' -ane 'print join(" ",@F[ map { 2 * $_ + 1} (0 .. $#F) ]),"\n";' < test.txt
```

**Explanation:**

- `-F'"'` set input separator to `"`
- `-a` turn autosplit on - this results in `@F` being filed with content of fields in the input
- `-n` iterate through all lines but don't print them by default
- `-e` execute code following
- `map { 2 * $_ + 1} (0 .. $#F)` generates a list of indexes (1,3,5 ...)
- `@F[map { 2 * $_ + 1} (0 .. $#F)]` takes a slice from the array, selecting only odd fields
- `join` - joins the slice with spaces

**NOTE:** I would not use this approach without a good reason, the first two are easier.

Some benchmarking (on a Raspberry Pi, with a 60000 lines input file and output thrown away to /dev/null)

- cut - 0m0.135s no surprise there
- sed - 0m5.864s
- perl - 0m8.218s - I guess regenerating the index list every line isn't that fast (with a hard coded slice list it goes to half, but that would defeat the purpose)
- the read based [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33276900/939457) - 0m52.027s

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F '"' '{ for(i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) { printf $i" " } print "" }'
```

### Explanation

`-F '"'` makes Awk treat quotation marks (`"`) as field delimiters. For example, Awk will split the line...

```
c1="a1" c2="b1" c3="cccc1"
```

...into fields numbered as...

```
1: 'c1='
2: 'a1'
3: ' c2='
4: 'b1'
5: ' c3='
6: 'cccc1'
7: ''
```

`for(i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) { printf $i" " }` starts at field 2, prints the value of the field, skips a field, and continues. In this case, fields 2, 4, and 6 will be printed.

`print` outputs a string following by a newline. `printf` also outputs a string, but doesn't append a newline. Therefore...

```
printf $i" "
```

...outputs the value of field `$i` followed by a space.

```
print ""
```

...simply outputs a newline.

Answer (score 1):

You can also look at the built-in *substring replacement/removal* bash offers. Either in a short script or *One-Liner*:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r line; do 
    new=${line//c[0-9]=/}  ## remove 'cX=', where X is '0-9'
    new=${new//\"/}        ## remove all '"' (double-quotes)
    echo "$new"
done <"$1"

exit 0
```

**Input**

```
$ cat dat/stuff.xml
c1="a1" c2="b1" c3="cccc1"

c1="aa2" c2="bbbb2" c3="cc2"

c1="aaaaaa3" c2="bb3" c3="cc3"
```

**Output**

```
$ bash parsexmlcx.sh dat/stuff.xml
a1 b1 cccc1

aa2 bbbb2 cc2

aaaaaa3 bb3 cc3
```

**As a One-Liner**

```
while read -r line; do new=${line//c[0-9]=/}; new=${new//\"/}; echo "$new"; done <dat/stuff.xml
```

Comment: It's easy for children to hurl insults, but it takes a person with integrity to provide a solution -- grow up.

Comment: Your comment was derogatory, and unhelpful. If you have something positive to contribute, by all means, please do. If on the other hand, you simply need to make yourself feel better or more important by criticizing answers different than your own -- please find another site to do that on. SO deserves better. You are either here to help, or you are on the wrong site. It's just plain sloppy to spawn an unnecessary subshell, when bash provides a builtin tool to do exactly what is needed.

Comment: Drop it OK, We just got off on the wrong foot. I'm willing to leave it at that.